# x86 multiple exceptions and interrupts at same time

Tags: x86

I want to know how to handle multi exceptions and interrupts at some time in x86. If there are a exception and interrupt at same time and the priority of interrupt is greater than exception. Is the exception discarded? or the exception will be handled later?